# Cypress How do you default the folders to closed when the test runner window pops up.

Tags: cypress

So, when my Cypress app opens up, all the folders are defaulted to open, I couldn't find a configuration to have them in a closed state when it launches.

How do you default the folders to a closed state, in cypress?

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be possible. Settings are stored per-project in the `cypress.json` file at the root of your project folder. I went through that file and I can confirm that there is not a setting for this.

If you would like to see this in Cypress in the future, consider [submitting a feature request on github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new?template=feature_request.md). I did a quick search and did not see this suggested anywhere.